# looker studio won't allow sorting / order properly by dates when date field is used in column on a pivot table

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I want to display total values for department but I need to show the departments as rows and the year-month as columns, over even just the month, but nor matter how I format my date or what type I use, the year-month will not show up in the right order in looker studio

what I want

| Dept | 2023-12 | 2023-11 | 2023-10 | 2023-09 | ....... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dep1 | val1 | val 1 | val 2 | val 2 | val 1 |
| dep2 | val 5 | val 6 | val 7 | val 8 | val 9 |

but this is what I'm getting

notice that 9 shows up before 10 from left to right

| Dept | 2023-12 | 2023-11 | 2023-09 | 2023-10 | ....... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dep1 | val1 | val 1 | val 2 | val 2 | val 1 |
| dep2 | val 5 | val 6 | val 7 | val 8 | val 9 |

what I have tried

my column dimension is called startDate and is a Date type

0. If I use the startDate as is in the column dimension the dates also appear all screwed up (ex. dec 27, dec 28, dec 29, dec 14, dec 15... and so on and so forth)
1. if I change the date to year-month it shows in the wrong order as shown above
2. if I create a calcualted field with FORMAT_DATETIME("%Y-%m",StartDate) it again shows in wrong order
3. I even tried with concat(year(startDate),"-",month(startDate)) but even so my headers show up like this: | Dept | 2023-12 | 2023-11 | 2023-9 | 2023-10 | ....... | ....
4. I also tried to simply change the startDate type to month but instead of numbers or months in the right order I get | Dept | December | November | September | October | ....... | ....

hours on this.. any help is appreciated it.

Answer (score 1):

I found what appears to be a workaround [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/146886718?pli=1) and there's gif with the solution [here](https://support.google.com/looker-studio/thread/26620922/unable-to-order-pivot-table-by-date?hl=en).

This is apparently a bug in looker.

solution:

what I had to do was to add another column dimension to the pivot table, (my startDate field), then I had to add it again, making sure the second column dimension being added was at the top, then I should be able to find the startDate in the sorting section, and the last thing to do would be to remove the extra startdate field.. and voila... the columns are now sorted accordingly

hope it helps someone